# raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]") pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tengo que calcular el BMI de un grupo de personas para luego calificarlo segun si es mayor o menor que 25. En caso de ser mayor, este valor debe ser reemplazado por 1, y en caso de ser menor, reemplazado por 0. El problema surge cuando intento hacer el filtro, ya que al usar el operador > me tira el error:

```
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
df["overweight"] = df["weight"] / (df["height"]/100)**2
if df[df["overweight"]] > 25.0:
  df.replace(df["overweight"], 1)
else:
  df.replace(df["overweight"], 0)
```

El link a la base de datos (para todo aquel que quiera correr una prueba) es [este](https://replit.com/@MatiasRico/boilerplate-medical-data-visualizer#medical_examination.csv).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

La parte del `if` está mal, el problema es que el `>` está fuera de los corchetes, es decir, no estas filtrando tu `df`

Para aplicar el filtro debería ser así: `df[df['overweight'] > 25.0]`

Ahora, hay una forma más fácil de hacer lo que quieres

Explicación:

1. El filtro que deseas, como lo vimos arriba, es `df['overweight'] > 25.0` o `df['overweight'] <= 25.0`
2. Para aplicar el filtro al dataframe ponemos el filtro dentro de los corchetes del dataframe `df[df['overweight'] > 25.0]`
3. Para seleccionar las filas del dataframe que cumplan con el filtro utilizamos el método `loc` `df.loc[df['overweight'] > 25.0]`
4. Para seleccionar la columna que deseamos lo ponemos como segundo parámetro dentro del `loc` `df.loc[df['overweight'] > 25.0, 'overweight']`
5. Y para finalizar podemos asignar el nuevo valor a cada fila `df.loc[df["overweight"] > 25.0, "overweight"] = 1`

Hay que tener cuidado de primero evaluar los `<= 25.0` porque si evalúas primero los mayores a 25, esos se convertirán en 1 y cuando evalúes los menores o iguales a 25.0 y los cambies por 0 entonces cambiarías también todos los que eran mayores a 25.0 pero que ahora son 1

El código completo quedaría así (Yo copié los datos de tu medical_examination.csv a un archivo local llamado sample.csv así que tendrás que utilizar tus datos):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df["overweight"] = df["weight"] / (df["height"]/100)**2
df.loc[df["overweight"] <= 25.0, "overweight"] = 0
df.loc[df["overweight"] > 25.0, "overweight"] = 1
print(df["overweight"])
```